# Cant get data from multiple tables using axios and EntityFramwork

Tags: vue.js, axios, entity-framework-core, nuxt.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting all the data inside the `<pre>` tags. But, I only getting Account table data into the table that I create for display. What changes are required to get the other table data also at the same time?

Next Application vue.js page code

```
        <tbody>
            <tr scope="row" v-for="(user, index) in posts" :key="user.Acc_ID">
            <td>
            <pre>{{user.Billings[0]}}</pre></td>
            <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Billings[0].[{"BillId"]}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Shippngs[0]['ShipId']}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.Email}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.EmailSub}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.PhoneCode}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.PhoneNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.AccAddress1}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.AccAddress2}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.AccDistrict}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.AccCity}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.BillAddress1}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.ShipAddress1}}</td>            
            <td>{{ user.Request}}</td>                     
            <td>{{ user.StartDate}}</td>         
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>   
    </div>
      <NuxtLink to="AccountDetailsPage">Account Information Page</NuxtLink><br>     <!--Link to next page -->
         <NuxtLink to="Accountbackup">Backup</NuxtLink>
  </b-container>
</div>     
</template>

<script>
// Importing axios to perform http methods
import axios from 'axios';  
var users;
export default {
    name: 'consume-rest-api',
    data(){
        return{
            posts: null
        }
    },
    data2(){    return{
            posts2: null,
            name2:null
        }
    },
    created() { //Get method axios 
        axios.get(`https://localhost:44394/api/accounts`)            
            .then(response => { 
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                this.posts = response.data    
                users = response['data']     
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log("Error Please check the connection")  
            });
    },
   
}
</script>
```

Asp.net core web api Get method to get three tables data at the same time using entiy framwork core.

```
    // GET: api/Accounts
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Account>>> GetAccounts()
    {
        var products = dbObj.Accounts
            .Include(p => p.Billings)
            .Include(q => q.Shippngs);

        return await products.ToListAsync(); ;
    }
```

Comment: When debug,can you get all the data in `products`?

Comment: Im getting data like this inside pre tags (I ommited some linse)
{
        "AccId": 57303,
        "Name": "Nipuni Nishadika",
        "BName": "NN store",
        "PhoneCode": 11,
        "Billings": [
            {
                "BillId": 87384,
                "BillAddress1": "Liyanagemulla",
                "AccId": 57303
            }
        ],
        "Shippngs": [
            {
                "ShipId": 77443,
                "ShipAddress1": "Liyanagemulla",
                "ShipAddress2": "Seeduwa",
                "AccId": 57303
            } ] },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is a misunderstanding here. I see that you're using `data2()` and `data()`. It's not correct. you should use one `data()` for your page like:

```
data(){
    return{
        posts: null,
        posts2: null,
        name2:null
    }
},
```

And then put any variables you want in there. It should fix your problem.

UPDATED

Adding a snippet for your situation, I implemented two ways for showing your data; the first way for showing the `Billings` field is recommended.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
        "AccId": 57303,
        "Name": "Nipuni Nishadika",
        "BName": "NNstore",
        "PhoneCode": 11,
        "PhoneNumber": 75485456,
        "AccAddress1": "Liyanagemulla",
        "AccAddress2": "Seeduwa",
        "AccCity": "Seeduwa",
        "AccDistrict": "colombo",
        "Email": "Nipuni@bistecglobal.com",
        "StartDate": "2021-04-10T00:00:00",
        "Billings": [{
          "BillId": 87384,
          "BillAddress1": "Liyanagemulla",
          "BillAddress2": "Seeduwa",
          "BillCity": "Seeduwa",
          "AccId": 57303
        }],
        "Shippngs": [{
          "ShipId": 77443,
          "ShipAddress1": "Liyanagemulla",
          "ShipAddress2": "Seeduwa",
          "ShipCity": "Seeduwa",
          "Request": "Callme",
          "EmailSub": "yes",
          "IsChecked": null,
          "AccId": 57303
        }]
      }, ]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AccID</th>
        <th>Billings</th>
        <th>Shippings</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.AccId">
        <td>{{ item.AccId }}</td>
        <td v-for="billing in item.Billings" :key="billing.BillId">{{ billing.BillId }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Shippngs[0].ShipId }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I remove data2() and put everything inside data(). But it didn't fix my issue. Do you have any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: Your welcome, Do you have any response from your server request?

Comment: {"AccId": 57303,"Name": "Nipuni Nishadika","BName": "NNstore","PhoneCode": 11,"PhoneNumber":75485456,"AccAddress1":"Liyanagemulla","AccAddress2":"Seeduwa","AccCity":"Seeduwa","AccDistrict":"colombo","Email":"Nipuni@bistecglobal.com","StartDate": "2021-04-10T00:00:00",
"Billings": [{"BillId": 87384,"BillAddress1": "Liyanagemulla","BillAddress2": "Seeduwa", "BillCity": "Seeduwa", "AccId": 57303 } ],
"Shippngs": [ {"ShipId":77443,"ShipAddress1":"Liyanagemulla","ShipAddress2": "Seeduwa","ShipCity": "Seeduwa", "Request": "Callme","EmailSub":"yes","IsChecked": null,"AccId": 57303 }]},

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all the data that I need from three tables. The issue is I can't set it to one table. I only getting account table data.                <td>{{ user.Billings[0].BillId}}</td> I tried this one but It's getting an error" Cannot read property."

Comment: I updated the answer and used `Vue` without `Nuxt` to show your situation. @NipuniWickramasinghe

Comment: If you find it helpful, please consider accepting. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. The first billing part solved my problem.  (<td v-for="billing in item.Billings" :key="billing.BillId">{{ billing.BillId }}</td> )Thank you so much again.